# What's the deal with changing pointers?

Tags: c++, c++11

I just have a quick question on the extraneous number (**1684096032**) outputted to the screen. I expected the integer ASCII value (97) to be outputted, as that is the ASCII value of lowercase `'a'`. The console gave me a ginormous number instead...

```
using namespace std;

int main(){
    char dadum[50] = "Papa Dadi";
    char* wicked = dadum;
    int* baboom = (int*)wicked;
    cout << baboom[1] << endl;
    cout<<"Hello World";

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: This isn't strictly a duplicate since there probably a reason you're getting the exact number you see, but have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/98650/what-is-the-strict-aliasing-rule.

Comment: The ASCII Value of lowercase a ( typecasted to an integer)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### A Word of Warning

Casting a a pointer to `int*` that wasn’t derived from an `int*` is undefined behavior, and the compiler is allowed to do literally anything.  This isn’t just theoretical: on some workstations I’ve coded on, an `int*` must be aligned on a four-byte boundary, whereas a `char*` might not be, trying to load a misaligned 32-bit value would cause a CPU fault, and therefore code like this might or might not crash at runtime with a “bus error.”

### Where 1684096032 Comes From

The compiler here is doing the “common-sense” thing for a desktop computer in 2019.  It’s letting you “shoot yourself in the foot,” so to speak, by emitting a load instruction from the address you cast to `int*`, no questions asked.  What you get is the garbage that CPU instruction gives you.

What’s going on is that `"Papa Dadi"` is stored as an array of bytes in memory, including the terminating zero byte.  It’s equivalent to, `{'P','a','p','a',' ','D','a','d', 'i', '\0'}`.  (`"Papa Dadi"` is just syntactic sugar.  You could write it either way)  These are stored as their ASCII values<sup>1</sup> `{ 0x50, 0x61, 0x70, 0x61, 0x20, 0x44, 0x61, 0x64, 0x69, 0x00 }`.

You happen to be compiling on a machine with four-byte `int`, so when you alias `wicked` to the `int* baboom`, `baboom[0]` aliases bytes 0–3 of `wicked` and `baboom[1]` bytes 4–7.  Therefore, on the implementation you tested, you happened to get back the bytes " Dad", or in Hex, 20 44 61 64.

Next, you happen to be compiling for a little-endian machine, so that gets loaded from memory in “back-words order,” `0x64614420`.

This has the decimal value `1684096032`.

### What You Meant to Do

Based on your remarks:<sup>2</sup>

```
cout << (int)wicked[1];
```

<sup>1</sup> Evidently you aren’t running on the sole exception, an IBM mainframe compiler.  These still use EBCDIC by default.

<sup>2</sup> [The consensus here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice) is **never** to write `using namespace std;`.  Personally, I learned to use `<iostream.h>` and the C standard library long before `namespace std` and I still prefer to omit `std` for those, so you can tell my code by the block of commands like `using std::cout;`.

Answer (score 2):

You are trying to print out the second value of integer array which points to the string "Papa Dadi"

You should know that the integer is 4-bytes and char is 1-byte. so each one element in the integer array will skip 4-bytes(characters)
the print out you see is "0x64614420" in hex, which when you think about big-endian you will see the following

0x20 is space character.

0x44 is 'D'

0x61 is 'a'

0x64 is 'd'

so you need to convert big-endian to little-endian if you care about order. however I am not sure what are you trying to achieve.